# API in Symfony and caching

Tags: symfony, memcached

I'm building a site in Symfony 2.0 that has a fair amount of AJAX, which builds page content with data it gets from an API, like:  http://mysite.com/api/pictures/list

Data is handled using Repositories, which are sometimes used in page code so that string of images you see might come from the controller using the PictureRepository, or via Ajax using the API which accesses the PictureRepository.

I'd like to use Memcached to ease the database load, but am not sure where to put the caching code.  Is it best to cache the database result, or the API result?  Or is the difference negligible?  Having the memcached logic inside the Repository would mean writing the code once (regardless of whether it's accessed via the API or directly), but it seems like it would also make sense to avoid accessing the Repository whenever possible.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that memcached should be used for session storage.
For your purposes you should better think about using of [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) as http cache.

After that, you can [configure your application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html) use [ESI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes).

At least, that is how we do it in our applications ;)